# Can't loop throu data inside HTML template with golang FIber

Tags: go, go-fiber

I am using Golang with Fiber and I have this function that is suppose to map all the datas to the frontend:

```
func ListWords(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db := database.DB.Db
    var words []models.Words
    db.Find(&words)
    return c.Render("public/views/getWords.html", fiber.Map{
        "name": words.Title,
                "cover": words.Cover,
    })}
```

My html file looks like this

```
{{ range . }}
{{.name}}-{{.cover}}
{{end}}
```

I am getting this error:
failed to execute: template: :11:6: executing "" at <.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}

I am still new to golang and I cant find good ressources online to solve this problem

Comment: The `.` in `range .` corresponds to the map you passed to render. There is nothing to range there, it is a map.

Comment: I may sound stupid but how can I map throu the map

Comment: When you iterate through a map, you get key-values. The template looks like you need to iterate through a slice of maps. Something like `fiber.Map{ "data": []map[string]any {...}}` and then `{{range .data}}`